# Convert UNIX Timestamp to any format desired?

Tags: java, android

For example:
I was able to get the timestamp

```
String date="123456765343";
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(date)*1000);
    Date d = cal.getTime(); // now this reprents the unix timestamp
```

I would like to have the date looking like this :

**14/Mar/2013 6:31:34 PM**

Comment: typical case of http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to use `SimpleDateFormat` (and you don't need the `Calendar`):

```
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(date) * 1000);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

Comment: thank you, it worked and you were right i do not need the `Calendar`

Comment: Some resources which explain more: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html , http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. And don't forget about locales !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your date.